# Cannot compile Next.js project with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I created a very simple Next.js project, that contains only one page, `index.js`, that looks like:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = () => {
    const [instance, setInstance] = useState()

    return (
        <></>
    );
};

const Home = () => <>
        <MyComponent />
</>;

export default Home;
```

When I run it in development mode, there is no error and everything is working fine.

But when I run `next build`, I get:

```
Error occurred prerendering page "/": Error: Minified React error #321; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=321 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
> Build error occurred
```

It looks like a problem with hooks, but I don't get what is wrong with my implementation. If I remove the line `const [instance, setInstance] = useState()`, the build is successful.

I am using next ^9.1.4, react ^16.12.0 and react-dom ^16.12.0.

Could you help me with this please? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just copy your code to pages/index.js and run `npm run build` (it has `next build` in it, and it works.

next 9.1.4
react, react-dom 16.12.0

[image]

My best guess... you have another next install globally? and `next build` use that next instead?

Or it could be the lib you installed, what package you have in your package.json?

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I run `next -v` in the command line, I get: `Next.js v9.1.4`. In my package.json, there is: `"next": "^9.1.4"`. So it seems the versions are matching...

Comment: ok hmmm....then my second guess is... hidden characters that you can't see.

Comment: I like this idea, but unfortunately after removing the buggy line and re-typing it manually, it still does not work :(

Comment: I'm running out of gas dude, lol :D
Try copy your code and put in codesandbox?

Comment: Omg, when I run `npm run build`, it works as well! But not with `next build`, even though "build" is just "next build" in package.json. I mark your answer as accepted as it helped me find the solution, even though I don't understand the problem with next build.